# Boundary Point of two sets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I wasn't able to prove this theorem,if anyone could guide me as to how to prove this would be extremely helpful.

If $\ a < b < c $ and the two sets $A$ and $B$ (both subsets of $\mathbb{R}$) has the property that $A\cap (a,c) = B\cap (a,c)$. Show that $b\in bd(A)$ if and only if $b\in bd(B).$

- here $bd(A)$ means set of boundary points of $A$.

Though it's iff problem but doing from one side suffices as the other half would be exactly the same method. So I assume that $b\in bd(B)$ which implies $\forall \epsilon > 0 $, we have $(b-\epsilon , b+\epsilon)\cap B \neq \phi$. So basically we get that $[B \cap (a,c)]\cap N(b,\epsilon)]$ is in $B$ and the rest of the elements are in $\mathbb{R}\setminus B$ and we can use the similar arguement for set $A$ with the same $\epsilon$ to prove that $b$ is a boundary point of $A$. Is my approach correct? I feel I have messed up the proof a little.

Answer (score 1):

It suffices to prove it for sufficently small $\epsilon>0$, because this proves the fact that $b \in \overline{A}$. Thus if you choose $\epsilon<\min (|a-b|,|b-c|)$ the assert should follow.

Comment: Here $\overbar{A}$ represnts closure of the set right?

Comment: Yes, it does. The property $A \cap (a,b)=B \cap (a,b)$ let us conclude $b \in bd(A)$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $b \in \operatorname{Bd}(A)$. Then let $U$ be an open set that contains $b$. Then $V=U \cap (a,c)$ is an open set that contains $b$ too, and so $V$ intersects $A$ and $A^\complement$ (and as $$V \cap A = A \cap (U \cap (a,c)) = U \cap (A \cap (a,c))=U \cap (B \cap (a,c)) = V \cap B$$ and similarly for the complement, as $$A \cap (a,c)= B \cap (a,c) \implies A^\complement \cap (a,c)=A^\complement \cap (a,c)$$ as well) we see that $b \in \operatorname{Bd}(B)$ as well. The reverse inclusion is shown the same way.

Note that this works for any open set $O$ with $b \in O$ and $A \cap O= B \cap O$ and in any space, not even a metric is needed.

Comment: A mistake I'd like to point out, that V doesn't contain b as the set (a,b) doesn't contain b, therefore it's intersection with U doesn't contain b.

Comment: @MayankJha I interchanged $b$ and $c$, sorry, now it's correct.

Comment: We can use U as the epsilon neighbourhood of b right?

Comment: @MayankJha if you want to use epsilon-neighbourhoods, you could.

Comment: Because for b to be a boundary point of B we want that neighbourhood to contain points both in B and complement of B, so using epsilon neighbourhood would be correct rather than any open set

Comment: @MayankJha for "boundary" we can use both epsilon-neighbourhoods or open sets, as we like. I use the general open sets in general, epsilon-neighbourhoods don't add new insights.

Comment: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BoundaryPoint.html.

Comment: See there it's mentioned in the definition as neighbourhood, not any arbitrary open set

Comment: @MayankJha an open set containing $x$ is also called a neighbourhood of $x$, also on that site.

Comment: Okay. I'm sorry I get confused a lot in open set and neighbourhood terms. Hope you understand